# installing windows XP on a laptop with problematic CD-ROM drive

Tags: windows-xp, installation, optical-drive

I'm trying to install windows XP on a old laptop which has a problematic CD-ROM drive unit. Sometime it reads the cds, but most of the times it didn't read the CD at all. Do you have any advices for me to follow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest getting an external USB drive. You'll want that anyway if the drive is already going out on your current laptop.

An alternative if you have a major brand like Dell or HP is to check eBay for a replacement.  Often if you have a model that sold several million units you can get good *new* replacements on eBay for reasonable prices.  I replaced the keyboard on my wife's Dell 3 times now, never paid more than $15, and a quick check shows I could replace the CD drive for $25 (normal combo drive) or $50 (dvd burner).

Answer (score 2):

This may sound obvious but have you tried cleaning the lens on the cd drive ?

Answer (score 1):

Eeeguides.com describes [how to install Windows XP using a USB pen drive](http://www.eeeguides.com/2007/11/installing-windows-xp-from-usb-thumb.html). The guide was  for installing XP on an EeePC netbook but should work on any PC.

It involves using some free utilities to make your USB drive bootable and then copy the XP install files from a XP install CD. As long as your laptop BIOS lets you boot from USB you can then install XP without the CD drive.

Answer (score 0):

You can also install Windows XP by a pen-drve, i have an Eee PC 904HD and every time that i need to install Windows XP or Windows Vista i install by my USB Stick.

Regards.